# ORA-00905: Missing Keyword error on select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I get an error in the below select query. This is the error I receive:

> ORA-00905: Missing Keyword

Can anyone help ?

```
SELECT ni.node_installation_id,ni.customer_node_id,ni.customer_id,c.brand_name_1,substr(nitr.name,1,instr(nitr.name, ' ')-1) as node_inst_type
    from node_installation ni , customer c , node_inst_type_release nitr
    where ( Case 
            WHEN ni.arne_timestamp is null  THEN ( case  
                                                   when ni.arne_flag ='I' then ni.arne_flag ='I'
                                                   END )
     else (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(ni.arne_timestamp) >= 60)
      end)     
and ni.customer_id = c.customer_id 
and ni.node_inst_type_release_id = nitr.node_inst_type_release_id
and ni.no_of_collection_node_missed >= 4
and c.customer_id =90;
```

Comment: Check your id's names where it is matching with the predefined id's of the database...
I am analyzing it further.

Comment: Please give a bit more info about the project you're working on. What did you already try?

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is in `case`:

```
( 
  case  
    when ni.arne_flag ='I' 
      then ni.arne_flag ='I'
  END 
)
```

I think the condition is totally wrong. Try change it to:

```
((ni.arne_timestamp is null and  ni.arne_flag ='I')
or
(trunc(sysdate) - trunc(ni.arne_timestamp) >= 60))
```

as below:

```
    SELECT ni.node_installation_id,
           ni.customer_node_id,
           ni.customer_id,
           c.brand_name_1,
           substr(nitr.name,1,instr(nitr.name, ' ')-1) as node_inst_type
     from node_installation ni , 
          customer c , 
          node_inst_type_release nitr
   where ((ni.arne_timestamp is null and  ni.arne_flag ='I')
          or
          (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(ni.arne_timestamp) >= 60))     
    and ni.customer_id = c.customer_id 
    and ni.node_inst_type_release_id = nitr.node_inst_type_release_id
    and ni.no_of_collection_node_missed >= 4
    and c.customer_id =90;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your inner CASE statement looks wrong to me, though I am not 100% why it should be syntactically incorrect :

```
CASE 
       WHEN ni.arne_flag = 'I' THEN **ni.arne_flag = 'I'**  END
```

The expression after the 'THEN' should be a value, I think, but in any case it is redundant.